# Selenium doesn't find ID in HTML using runScript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'm a selenium noob and I'm trying to display the value of "demo" ID from [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid)

Running this in a separate JS injector works fine:
window.frames["iframeResult"].document.getElementById("demo")

But the same code fails when I run it from selenium runScript command:

```
javascript{alert(window.frames["iframeResult"].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  )}
```

It fails with this error: `[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: window.frames.iframeResult is undefined.`

Comment: Using Selenium you can consider to switch to the frame first. Then execute the javascript. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB How do I first switch to the frame ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaScripts can be executed in Selenium Webdriver using `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("");`

To use Selenium methods you can use `getText()` method to get the text of an element and `getAttribute()` method to get the attribute value of that element.

Since the `iframeResult` is a frame, first switch to the frame by using `driver.switchTo().frame()` method then use the above methods depends on need.